# Updating $PATH on mac to use new version of a file

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext2, bash

I originally installed the Elm v0.16 version of elm-format https://github.com/avh4/elm-format. I don't remember how I set it up but a new Elm v0.17 has been released and elm-format was updated. I downloaded the new elm-format file but when I type elm-format into the terminal it still shows the old version:
`elm-format 0.2.0-alpha`.

I thought I added it to my path but I'm not sure because I don't see anything but this on my path when I run `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

How do I make it so that when I run elm-format it uses the latest version that I just downloaded? I had configured the previous version of elm-format to work with sublime text as well but now I can't update sublime to use the new elm-format either and it defaults to using the old version of elm-format, resulting in improper syntax.

Additionally, since the latest version of Elm has new syntax and idioms, when writing code in sublime it is still trying to use the old syntax and highlights my Elm 0.17 syntax with the hot pink incorrect syntax highlight.

I can't even find where or how the old version of elm-format exists but for some reason it's the default version.

I don't know if it's relevant but this is my current .bash_profile that I apparently never altered to make work with the old version of elm-format:

```
# STYLING & COLORS
# ################


## LSCOLORS
#> http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/21/add-color-to-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x/
#> http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100297/changing-terminal-color

export CLICOLOR=1
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
export LSCOLORS=exBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx


## Prompt Style/Colors
#> http://blog.taylormcgann.com/2012/06/13/customize-your-shell-command-prompt/
#> http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html

export PS1_OLD=$PS1
export PS1="\[\033[1;35m\]\W \[\033[1;91m\]♥\[\033[0;36m\] "
```

In Sublime, under Preferences > Package Settings > Elm Language Support > User Settings I have:

```
{
    "elm_format_on_save": true,
    "elm_paths": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/elm-format"
}
```

All in all I'm totally confused and frustrated as I can't even write code without hot pink highlights all over it.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related sites http://apple.stackexchange.com  (AskDifferently) OR http://SuperUser.com . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run `which elm_format` to show the location of the old 0.16 version. You can then replace that binary with the new one you got from github. From the sublime path it looks like you've placed a binary of elm_format on the root of the hard drive. You may want to put it inside `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thanks for the input gusto. Running `which elm-format` returns `/usr/local/bin/elm-format`. I went to the the user/local/bin folder in the finder and just copy+pasted the new `elm-format` and replaced the old elm-format that was there so now when I run `elm-format` in the terminal the new version is returned. However, I think there is something wrong because the new elm-format file has a different file icon than the old one, which was the same as all the other files around it,  and it also has a very large file size relative to everything else. http://postimg.org/image/nj2wg6j81/ Any thoughts?